# What happens after TCP ZeroWindow is introduced?

Tags: ssl, curl, tcp, ssl-certificate, wireshark

In client/server communication, I am seeing  TCP ZeroWindow from client.

What is an expected scenario(what flags are set and send) after this situation?

Below are the possible logs I am getting. In this case server sends RST packet to terminate the connection.Why this has happened?

CLIENT(HP UX machine), server (RHEL machine)

Wireshark dump on server

```
17:55:03.756500     TCP 62  58304 → 1556 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1
17:55:03.756522     TCP 62  1556 → 58304 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14600 
                    Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=128
17:55:03.760562     TLSv1.2 571 Client Hello
17:55:03.760588     TCP 54  1556 → 58304 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=15744 
                    Len=0
17:55:03.769564     TCP 1514    1556 → 58304 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=15744 
                    Len=1460 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
17:55:03.769588     TLSv1.2 618 Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key 
                    Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
17:55:03.769689     TCP 60  58304 → 1556 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=1461 Win=32768 
                    Len=0
17:55:03.828427     TCP 60  58304 → 1556 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=2025 Win=32768 
                    Len=0
17:55:23.789662     TLSv1.2 61  Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected 
                    Message)
17:55:23.789748     TCP 54  1556 → 58304 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2032 Ack=518 
                    Win=15744 Len=0
17:55:23.789951     TCP 60  58304 → 1556 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=2033 Win=32768 
                    Len=0
17:55:25.662787     TLSv1.2 192 [TCP ZeroWindow] , Certificate, Client Key 
                    Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake 
                    Message
17:55:25.662798     TCP 54  1556 → 58304 [RST] Seq=2033 Win=0 Len=0
```

Client curl logs

```
Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
Info: Cipher selection: 
ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
Info: successfully set certificate verify locations:
Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
Info: error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unexpected 
message
Info: Closing connection 0
```

The question is what is an expected flow of control when TCP ZeroWindow occurs and how communication is restarted after ZeroWindow timeout?

Below is what is in description of an ALERT packet. Really not sure what is un expected.

```
Transmission Control Protocol,Seq: 2025, Ack: 518, Len: 7

[Stream index: 2439]
[TCP Segment Len: 7]
Sequence number: 2025    (relative sequence number)
[Next sequence number: 2032    (relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment number: 518    (relative ack number)
0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window size value: 123
[Calculated window size: 15744]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x9e59 [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent pointer: 0
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
    [iRTT: 0.004062000 seconds]
    [Bytes in flight: 7]
    [Bytes sent since last PSH flag: 7]
TCP payload (7 bytes)
Secure Sockets Layer
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message)
    Content Type: Alert (21)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 2
    Alert Message
        Level: Fatal (2)
        Description: Unexpected Message (10)
```

Please let me what else information might be helpful to get through.

Answer (score 0):

The peer advertises a different window size, possibly in response to a window probe. However the zero window is only on the final RST so it isn't relevant.

The server has sent a FIN/ACK before the final RST. Don't overlook it. Probably you have sent it something it didn't like, in this case probably the client certificate.

Comment: Second last line also has zero window. Anyways the issue is intermittent. But why wireshark/tcp is not showing what is unexpected?

Answer (score -1):

In this case the above issue was because of **connctionTimeout** set by tomcat.

standard **server.xml** that ships with Tomcat sets this to 20000 (i.e. 20 seconds).

**ConnectionTimeout** is the number of milliseconds tomcat Connector will wait, after accepting a connection for client to present request uri line.

If we carefully look at wireshark dump, we clearly see 20 sec delay in between in handshaking itself and than ALERT.

So in this case slow client delayed http request for 20 sec on the socket after setting up a tcp connection and hence tomcat ignored that socket.

Tomcat set this timeout in order to prevent DOS attack.

For more on connectionTimeout read https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html
For more on DOS with connectionTimeout read http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/137cxfqtr5/http-connection-timout

Comment: Incorrect. Tomcat cannot send TLS alerts. Only the TLS layer can do that. The problem is clearly the 'unexpected message'. You don't get unexpected messages and a read timeout at he same time. It doesn't make sense. The alert and 20 second delay came in the middle of the handshake, not after it.

Comment: "The alert and 20 second delay came in the middle of the handshake" isn't that a reason for unexpected message if data transfer was happening and socket timed out?

Comment: How can a socket time out if there is a message? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It helped me dig more into an issue. Our setup uses pbx connector to provide single port access which accepts connection and then handover that connection to tomcat. With that endpoint connector we also set soTimeout with same value as connectionTimeout. Increased connectionTimeout resolved an issue.

Comment: With your comment above I think you are referring readTimeout as socketTimeout. Yes 20 sec delay is in the middle of handshake and that referes to connectionTimeout. Please correct me if I am wrong.